# XOR Decryption with multiple encrypted strings

Tags: string, xor, encryption

The problem is I have 11 encrypted strings having around 100 chars each. I'm not writing the strings here, because I don't want the full solution, I just need the way I should follow.

11 strings XOR'ed with a key string. I don't know the encryption key but I should be able to decrypt one of those. I can write it in java or C. Capitalized letters might give some information about spaces. (If you xor lowercase with space it'll be uppercase and vice versa.)

Which way should I follow? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking for a decryption algorithm or for a key-breaking algorithm?

Comment: It's not keybreaking. It's decryption.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No one answered my question so I'm answering my own question. Here : This makes the answers readable and you can guess the missing parts of the cypher.

```
public class ThisIsTheOne {
    public static void main(String[] args){     

        char [][] strings = {{0x31,0x5c,0x4e,0xea,0xa8,0xb5,0xf8,0xaa,0xf9,0x17,0x41,0x45,0xbf,0x43,0xe1,0x78,0x4b,0x8f,0xa0,0x0d,0xc7,0x1d,0x88,0x5a,0x80,0x4e,0x5e,0xe9,0xfa,0x40,0xb1,0x63,0x49,0xc1,0x46,0xfb,0x77,0x8c,0xdf,0x2d,0x3a,0xff,0x02,0x1d,0xff,0xf5,0xb4,0x03,0xb5,0x10,0xd0,0xd0,0x45,0x54,0x68,0xae,0xb9,0x86,0x22,0xb1,0x37,0xda,0xe8,0x57,0x55,0x3c,0xcd,0x88,0x83,0xa7,0xbc,0x37,0x52,0x0e,0x06,0xe5,0x15,0xd2,0x2c,0x95,0x4e,0xba,0x50,0x25,0xb8,0xcc,0x57,0xee,0x59,0x41,0x8c,0xe7,0xdc,0x6b,0xc4,0x15,0x56,0xbd,0xb3,0x6b,0xbc,0xa3,0xe8,0x77,0x43,0x01,0xfb,0xca,0xa3,0xb8,0x3b,0x22,0x08,0x09,0x56,0x09,0x87,0x81,0x5f,0x65,0x28,0x67,0x64,0x70,0x3d,0xe0,0xf3,0xd5,0x24,0x40,0x0a,0x19,0xb1,0x59,0x61,0x0b,0x11,0xef,0x3e},
                             {0x23,0x4c,0x02,0xec,0xbb,0xfb,0xaf,0xa3,0xed,0x18,0x51,0x0a,0xbd,0x11,0xfa,0x72,0x4f,0xcd,0xa2,0x01,0x8a,0x1a,0x83,0x42,0xcf,0x06,0x4b,0xbd,0xe5,0x48,0xb1,0x2b,0x07,0xdf,0x44,0xba,0x71,0x91,0xd9,0x60,0x6e,0xf4,0x08,0x1f,0xfd,0xe5,0xad,0x46,0xa5,0x06,0x9d,0x9f,0x7f,0x54,0x3b,0xed,0xb9,0xc8,0x61,0xbf,0x29,0xc7,0xe2,0x05,0x13,0x2e,0xda,0x93,0x82,0xb0,0xbc,0x2c,0x5c,0x4b,0x45,0xf9,0x19,0xcf,0x3a,0x9f,0x1c,0xb7,0x41,0x51,0xf6,0xd5,0x51,0xf4,0x48,0x0c,0x82,0xb2,0xcb,0x24,0xcc,0x5b,0x02,0x8a,0xa7,0x6e,0xb7,0xb4,0xab,0x24,0x17,0x1a,0xb3,0xcd,0xad,0xb8,0x35,0x6f},
                             {0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xa9,0xa7,0xb2,0xbb,0xa9,0xb8,0x00,0x5d,0x43,0xa3,0x04,0xb5,0x71,0x4c,0xc0,0xbb,0x0c,0x8a,0x34,0x88,0x4d,0xd9,0x13,0x04,0xb8,0xad,0x40,0xb6,0x2b,0x07,0xdf,0x44,0xba,0x6e,0x9d,0x8a,0x23,0x68,0xe5,0x1d,0x04,0xe0,0xe7,0xb2,0x07,0xb7,0x0b,0x9b,0x82,0x61,0x11,0x2b,0xac,0xb6,0xc8,0x66,0xa2,0x32,0xdf,0xe2,0x57,0x52,0x7d,0xc2,0x93,0x98,0xf5,0xf3,0x25,0x1a,0x0d,0x47,0xe5,0x03,0xc6,0x6e,0x93,0x5d,0xe8,0x12,0x30,0xb5,0x9b,0x7a,0xfb,0x5f,0x41,0xaf,0xa8,0xd6,0x61,0xcb},
                             {0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xa9,0xaa,0xb2,0xa8,0xa4,0xfd,0x06,0x41,0x4f,0xb5,0x17,0xb5,0x60,0x5c,0xc0,0xaa,0x0d,0xc9,0x1a,0x89,0x08,0xc2,0x06,0x4b,0xa8,0xad,0x5e,0xa0,0x6a,0x02,0x90,0x56,0xf4,0x7a,0x8a,0xd3,0x30,0x6e,0xf5,0x02,0x1e,0xaf,0xe1,0xac,0x01,0xa8,0x11,0x97,0x84,0x7a,0x5c,0x68,0xa1,0xb7,0x87,0x69,0xa3,0x7b,0xc8,0xf4,0x57,0x54,0x32,0xc1,0x98,0xcc,0xb4,0xef,0x63,0x59,0x02,0x56,0xe3,0x05,0xcd,0x3a,0x95,0x44,0xee,0x41,0x60,0xea,0xd4,0x5a,0xef,0x52,0x04,0x89,0xe7,0xda,0x7d,0x83,0x54,0x02,0xbc,0xa6,0x70,0xbd,0xa8,0xeb,0x77,0x52,0x00,0xb8,0xda,0xbb,0xba,0x24,0x6b,0x13,0x0f,0x04,0x0d,0x8e,0xc6,0x44,0x7e,0x2c,0x76,0x7f,0x3d,0x30,0xed,0x81,0xea,0x2e,0x4c,0x14,0x04,0xe1,0x31,0x5a,0x10,0x10,0xe7,0x22,0x9b,0xe6,0x63,0x6a,0xaa},
                             {0x3f,0x56,0x1b,0xa9,0xad,0xb4,0xb6,0xeb,0xec,0x54,0x42,0x4b,0xa3,0x17,0xb5,0x64,0x41,0x8f,0xac,0x0d,0xd3,0x5f,0x8c,0x08,0xd3,0x1a,0x1f,0xe9,0xe2,0x4f,0xe5,0x68,0x08,0xc2,0x13,0xf1,0x7c,0x81,0xd9,0x60,0x7c,0xee,0x02,0x1d,0xaf,0xe1,0xe0,0x01,0xb2,0x1a,0xde,0x87,0x7a,0x5e,0x68,0xbe,0xa8,0x8d,0x61,0xb9,0x3a,0xc5,0xee,0x0d,0x56,0x2e,0x8e,0x95,0x82,0xf5,0xef,0x37,0x5f,0x0a,0x4a,0xe2,0x0e,0xd8,0x6e,0x93,0x5d,0xe8,0x12,0x30,0xb5,0x9b,0x73,0xfb,0x43,0x02,0xcd,0x95,0xd7,0x70,0xc6,0x5b,0x40,0xaa,0xa0,0x65,0xf2,0xa5,0xe3,0x3a,0x5a,0x0b,0xb5,0xdc,0xab,0xa4,0x37,0x22,0x13,0x0f,0x04,0x2f,0x8e,0xc8,0x5b,0x7c,0x20,0x70},
                             {0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xfb,0xac,0xfb,0xb9,0xbe,0xfd,0x54,0x41,0x5d,0xa2,0x43,0xe1,0x69,0x5e,0xca,0xbd,0x58,0xc5,0x19,0xcd,0x4b,0xd2,0x06,0x1b,0xbd,0xe2,0x4e,0xb7,0x6a,0x19,0xd8,0x4a,0xba,0x34,0xd8,0xde,0x28,0x7b,0xe8,0x4d,0x07,0xe7,0xe9,0xa3,0x0e,0xe7,0x14,0x97,0x9c,0x7e,0x11,0x23,0xa8,0xbd,0x98,0x22,0xa3,0x3e,0xca,0xf5,0x12,0x47,0x2e,0x8e,0x8f,0x8d,0xb3,0xf9,0x63,0x5c,0x19,0x49,0xe6,0x40,0xc6,0x21,0x85,0x4e,0xba,0x0d,0x79,0xec,0xcf,0x52,0xff,0x11,0x12,0x84,0xb4,0xcc,0x61,0xd1,0x19,0x02,0xae,0xbc,0x66,0xf2,0xb2,0xe4,0x36,0x43,0x4e,0xac,0xc0,0xab,0xa9,0x38,0x22,0x0b,0x08,0x48,0x00,0xc2,0xca,0x4e,0x69,0x35,0x22,0x64,0x35,0x73,0xb2,0xc4,0xce,0x35,0x05,0x0b,0x0c,0xf7,0x74,0x20,0x1f,0x0f,0xe5,0x2a,0xc9,0xf2,0x6d,0x71,0xb6,0xcf,0x61,0xa7,0x11,0xcc,0x22,0x9f,0x77,0xac,0xe7,0xaa,0x88,0xa2,0xf1,0x99,0x83,0x12,0x2b,0x11,0xbe,0x87,0xa5,0x9c,0x35,0x5d,0x25,0xf8,0xe4},
                             {0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xfb,0xac,0xfb,0xb9,0xbe,0xfd,0x54,0x41,0x5d,0xa2,0x43,0xe1,0x69,0x5e,0xca,0xbd,0x58,0xc5,0x19,0xcd,0x4b,0xd9,0x0f,0x1f,0xa6,0xea,0x5b,0xa4,0x7b,0x01,0xc9,0x09,0xba,0x76,0x96,0xcf,0x60,0x6e,0xf4,0x0c,0x04,0xaf,0xe1,0xac,0x0a,0xa8,0x14,0x8d,0xd0,0x66,0x59,0x2d,0xed,0x9f,0x87,0x74,0xb5,0x29,0xc7,0xea,0x12,0x5d,0x29,0x8e,0x88,0x83,0xf5,0xe9,0x30,0x5f,0x4b,0x44,0xf9,0x15,0xcb,0x2b,0xd0,0x5a,0xf5,0x13,0x73,0xfd,0x9b,0x4a,0xf5,0x11,0x03,0x9f,0xa2,0xd9,0x6f,0x83,0x41,0x4a,0xaa,0xf2,0x61,0xbd,0xa2,0xe9,0x7b,0x17,0x0f,0xb5,0xcc,0xe2,0xa5,0x3e,0x67,0x5c,0x15,0x4c,0x0d,0x96,0x81,0x59,0x69,0x34,0x77,0x7e,0x22,0x75,0xb3,0x81,0xce,0x2e,0x40,0x58,0x2a,0xfe,0x67,0x65,0x0b,0x13,0xe7,0x22,0x87,0xff,0x22,0x70,0xab,0xcf,0x73,0xbb,0x02,0x89,0x32,0x83,0x6f,0xbd,0xec,0xfe,0xce,0xe0,0xa3,0xb8,0x94,0x47,0x3c,0x1b,0xbe,0xb6,0xb4,0x91,0x3a,0x53,0x6c,0xe4,0xf9,0xb1,0x3f,0x1e,0xff,0xf7,0x1e,0xa3,0x13,0xc8,0x66,0x1d,0xd9,0xa4,0xce},
                             {0x31,0x5c,0x4e,0xea,0xa8,0xb5,0xf8,0xbf,0xfd,0x11,0x15,0x5e,0xa5,0x06,0xb5,0x60,0x41,0xc6,0xa0,0x0c,0x8a,0x08,0x85,0x4d,0xd2,0x1a,0x4b,0xbd,0xe5,0x4c,0xe5,0x68,0x01,0xd9,0x43,0xba,0x70,0x8b,0x8a,0x35,0x74,0xf4,0x0c,0x00,0xff,0xf9,0xe0,0x0f,0xa1,0x43,0x9f,0xd0,0x65,0x43,0x27,0xa3,0xbf,0xc8,0x60,0xb9,0x2f,0x89,0xee,0x04,0x13,0x2e,0xcb,0x92,0x98,0xf5,0xfd,0x2d,0x5e,0x4b,0x45,0xe4,0x0e,0xcc,0x3b,0x9d,0x59,0xe9,0x41,0x7d,0xf7,0xc9,0x5b,0xba,0x41,0x0e,0x9a,0xa2,0xca,0x24,0xc5,0x47,0x4d,0xa2,0xf2,0x76,0xba,0xa3,0xac,0x32,0x59,0x18,0xb2,0xda,0xad,0xa4,0x3d,0x67,0x12,0x15,0x04,0x41,0xc2,0xe0,0x4f,0x65,0x65,0x51,0x7f,0x31,0x7d,0xa9,0xd3},
                             {0x27,0x19,0x46,0xf9,0xbb,0xb2,0xae,0xad,0xec,0x11,0x18,0x41,0xa8,0x1a,0xbc,0x30,0x0e,0xca,0xa0,0x1b,0xd8,0x06,0x9d,0x5c,0xc9,0x10,0x05,0xe9,0xfe,0x4a,0xad,0x6e,0x04,0xd5,0x13,0xe9,0x6d,0x99,0xde,0x25,0x69,0xbc,0x5e,0x50,0xee,0xec,0xa7,0x09,0xb5,0x0a,0x8a,0x98,0x7f,0x42,0x64,0xed,0xb6,0x89,0x6f,0xb5,0x37,0xd0,0xa7,0x16,0x13,0x2d,0xdc,0x93,0x8f,0xb0,0xf8,0x36,0x48,0x0e,0x06,0xed,0x0f,0xcd,0x6e,0x97,0x59,0xf4,0x04,0x62,0xf9,0xcf,0x57,0xf4,0x56,0x41,0x86,0xa2,0xc1,0x77,0x8f,0x15,0x43,0xef,0xa2,0x70,0xbd,0xa5,0xe9,0x33,0x42,0x1c,0xbe,0x88,0xa4,0xa5,0x22,0x22,0x19,0x0f,0x47,0x1e,0x9b,0xd1,0x5f,0x65,0x2b,0x65,0x3b,0x70,0x71,0xae,0xc5,0x9a,0x27,0x05,0x08,0x1f,0xfe,0x72,0x65,0x1d,0x08,0xf8,0x22,0xc9,0xed,0x6d,0x76,0xe4,0x8b,0x63,0xab,0x15,0xd0,0x20,0x85,0x73,0xa7,0xee,0xf0,0x27},
                             {0x46,0x6d,0x06,0xec,0xe9,0x98,0xb7,0xa2,0xfb,0x1d,0x46,0x4f,0xed,0x2c,0xed,0x76,0x41,0xdd,0xaa,0x3c,0xc3,0x1c,0x99,0x41,0xcf,0x11,0x0a,0xbb,0xf4,0x09,0xed,0x39,0x59,0x80,0x05,0xb3,0x39,0x9c,0xcf,0xaf,0xb6,0x1d,0x03,0x15,0xfc,0xa0,0xa3,0x14,0xbe,0x13,0x8a,0x9f,0x32,0x50,0x3b,0xed,0xac,0x80,0x67,0xf0,0x3a,0xdb,0xf3,0x57,0x5c,0x3b,0x8e,0xdc,0x9b,0xa7,0xf5,0x37,0x53,0x05,0x41,0xab,0x0f,0x9f,0x3c,0xd0,0x4f,0xf5,0x0d,0x66,0xf1,0xd5,0x59,0xba,0x52,0x0e,0x89,0xa2,0xcb,0x2a,0x83},
                             {0x32,0x51,0x0b,0xa9,0xba,0xbe,0xbb,0xbe,0xfd,0x00,0x15,0x47,0xa8,0x10,0xe6,0x71,0x49,0xca,0xee,0x11,0xd9,0x45,0xcd,0x7f,0xc8,0x1a,0x05,0xe9,0xf8,0x5a,0xac,0x65,0x0e,0x90,0x52,0xba,0x6a,0x8c,0xd8,0x25,0x7b,0xf1,0x4d,0x13,0xe6,0xf0,0xa8,0x03,0xb5,0x4f,0xde,0x9e,0x77,0x47,0x2d,0xbf,0xf8,0x9d,0x71,0xb5,0x7b,0xdd,0xef,0x12,0x13,0x36,0xcb,0x85,0xcc,0xb8,0xf3,0x31,0x5f,0x4b,0x52,0xe3,0x01,0xd1,0x6e,0x9f,0x52,0xf9,0x04}};

        char[][] answer = new char [11][83];    
        int k=0, l=0;   
        int i = 0, j=0;
        int count = 0; 
        for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
            for (j=0; j<=82; j++){
                if (j>82 || l>82) break; 
                count = 0;
                l=j;
                for (k=0;k<=10;k++) { 
                    if (i==k){
                        k++;
                    }
                    if (j>82 || l>82 || i >10 || k>10) break; 
                    char temp = (char) (strings [i][j] ^ strings[k][l]);
                    if (temp == 32  || (temp > 64 && temp <91) || (temp >96 && temp <123) ) {
                        count++;
                        if (count>4)        
                            answer[i][j] = ' ';         
                        else
                            answer[i][j] = (char) (temp ^ ' ');     
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.print("\nString "+ i+"- ");
            for (j=0; j<=82; j++) {
                l = j;                                          
                System.out.print(answer[i][j]);                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```